# Positioning the website correctly in the mobile version

Tags: html, mobile

I'm trying to format the mobile version of my website but the layout is not centered. How can I do it?

Code to turn mobile version:

```
[<Meta name = "viewport" width = "device-width, initial-scale = 0.9, maximum-scale = 0.9, user-scalable = no">][1]
```

My website is like this #1, I would like it were so #2

[image]